# CORS error when Apps Manager calls cloudfoundryapplication endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, health-check

I have two applications with exact same CORS settings and same configuration. Enabled `health` and `info` actuators on both:

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /manage
      exposure:
        include: "info,health"
```

However, one shows health info in TAS Apps Manager while the other doesn't.

Looking at Network tab in Apps Manager, I see this error for the second deployment:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://my-app.apps.pcf.something.net/api/cloudfoundryapplication' 
from origin 'https://apps.system.something.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: 

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch 
the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Right after that, there is a `preflight` request that fails with 403. In my CORS settings all the HTTP methods are allowed: `"HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTION"`

Checking the dependencies, they are also almost identical. I mean there is nothing that seems to me related to CloudFoundry that exist in either of the repositories. All I added was:

```kotlin
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

Is there anything that I missed here? I went through many documentation and I even added the following properties but no luck:

```yaml
management:
  cloudfoundry:
    enabled: true
    skip-ssl-validation: true
```

I have also tried enabling/disabling `csrf` as well as `cors` in Spring Security without any positive result.

Both repositories are on Spring Boot version `3.0.5`, however, I noticed one small difference. With the working deployment with `health` endpoint I also see `/health/liveness` and `/health/readiness` but with the other one that is failing to show health information I don't see the two sub-paths. I can only see `/health` and again this is another mystery because their configuration are exactly the same and they both have `cloud` profile as active profile.

If there is anything you need please let me know and I'll update the question.